# Masking visibility of text within a div with overflow:hidden and GreenSock

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, gsap

I am trying to slide a div over another div with text inside, however I don't want the text to move with the div, I just want the div to slide over the text (and mask/hide it) while the text stays where it is.

I'm still a newbie so my apologies in advance if this doesn't make sense :D Here is a reference that is super similar to what I'm trying to achieve, however instead of the text falling, I just want the div to slide over the text (and hide it) without the text moving at all:

[ref](https://codepen.io/sgorneau/pen/bZeNbb)

Here's their code:

html:

```
<div>
 <h2>test,</h2>
 <h2>test,</h2>
 <h2>test.</h2>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 5;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #efefef;

 /* Overflow HERE .. not on the
 elements being tweened */
overflow: hidden;


 h2{
 position: relative;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 33.3%;
 margin: 2px 4px;
 }
}
```

js:

```
let preloaderAnim = new TimelineMax();
preloaderAnim.staggerTo('h2', 1, { y:'200%', delay: 1}, .15);
```

I've heard that overflow:hidden might be useful, but I'm not sure how to use it in this case...

I would also like to use GreenSock for the animation!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of GSAP (or at least the old syntax). You should use [this](https://greensock.com/get-started/) to learn about how to use GSAP.

Comment: Hey @ZachSaucier! glad to see you here)